# Запаролить SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Всем доброго дня! 
Хочу использовать SQLite в своем проекте, защитив ее паролем. В гугле [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible) такие решения:

```
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=advsettings.db;Version=3;");
    conn.SetPassword("password");
    conn.Open();

    SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;"
          + "CREATE TABLE person("
          + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
          + "first_name TEXT, "
          + "last_name TEXT, "
          + "sex INTEGER, "
          + "birth_date INTEGER);"
          + "INSERT INTO person(first_name, last_name, sex, birth_date) "
          + "VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 0, strftime('%s', '1979-12-10'));";

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    conn.Close();
```

Но оно почему-то не работает для меня: код выполняется без ошибок. И я надеюсь, что не смогу зайти в БД и просматривать структуру БД без пароля, но DB Browser for SQLite позволяет просмотреть без проблем. Более того, я из своего кода я так же могу открыть БД без пароля и сделать в ней запись.

Пробовал так же вариант с

```
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=advsettings.db;Version=3;");
    //conn.SetPassword("password");
    conn.Open();

    conn.ChangePassword("mypassword");
```

В этом случае получаю ошибку:

> file is encrypted or is not a database
>   not an error

Почему у меня не работает способ, описанный выше?

PS: использую `System.Data.SQLite;`

Comment: ты еще было указание что это должно было быть первое действие с базой

Comment: @Grundy. так это и было первое действие с базой. Я удаляю файл и запускаю первый код. Файл БД создается, и дальше я почему-то могу его открыть без пароля